# Horizontally center a height-variant image without distorting image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="..." style="position: fixed; height: 80%;" />
</div>
```

Image height is set to be proportionate with the window height, how to make it fixed yet centred, also without distorting the images.

Because width of the images also vary with height, can't just get width and do the 'left:0; margin-left: -width/2' trick.

Thanks!

Comment: you can try css `#container img {margin: auto}`

Comment: @thecodeparadox: added that, plus add 'text-align:center' in '.container', nothing changes :( .

Comment: its a class not a id so .container not #container... honest mistake

Comment: if i could see your css it would help too :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are able to use the following styles, it will do the job.

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

img {
    position: relative;
    height: 80%;
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/9qKsj/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the position fixed, you'll need some javascript. See [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/satgw/5/)

html:

```
<img id="img" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/81/Mdna-standard-edition-cover.jpg" />
```

​css:

```
#img {
    position: fixed;
    height: 80%;
}
```

​js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        $('#img').css('margin-left', ($(window).width() - $('#img').width())/2);        
    }).resize();        
});​
```

Comment: Not really. Even keeping fixed position it can be done with CSS only.

Comment: @VisioN Ah yes I see.. your solution is better indeed! I upvoted it:)

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  margin: 5px/*top bottom*/ auto/*left and right*/;
}
```

if you want it right in the middle and no matter if you scroll or anything use #thecodeparadox's answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this example http://dabblet.com/gist/2787939 help? It is centered and elastic.